# Javascript How do i call functions from an array of function names

Tags: javascript

```
var action = ['function1','function2' etc ]
var obj = new objectcreate ();

for (functionname in action){
    obj+'.'+action[variablename]+'()';      
}
```

the functions are already generated I just wanna go through an array and execute all the functions it  on the object i created 
thanks for your help

Comment: `for (functionname in action)` doesn't do what you think; `functionname` will be properties of the Array, which may not be in numerical order and can return other properties depending on browser. **Never** use `for...in` on Array. Instead use the plain old C-style loop `for(var i= 0; i<array.length; i++)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj[action[functionname]]();` will do the trick.

Comment: what if you didn't have an array of function names? Could this still be done?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign I don't get you. If you have no function names available, the best you could do is enumerate all the fields of the objects and invoke those which are functions.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this.

```
obj[action[functionName]]();
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above worked for me.

Noting that we are 10.5 years on from the original post the chances are JS have evolved.

My solution is:

```
window[action[functionName]]();
```

A solution tailored to the original question is as follows:

```
var action = ['test1','test2'];


function test1(){
   alert("test 1 running");
}

function test2(){
    alert("test 2 running");
}

for (var i=0; i<action.length; i++){
    window[action[i]]();
}
```

Expected output is an alert box saying "test 1 running" followed by another alert box saying "test 2 running".