# How do I access JS functions from an array storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, html5-canvas

I'm working with custom "buttons" in html5 canvas. Because I've got so many buttons I think it makes more sense to store then in an array.  My dilemma is, I'm not quite sure on how to implement custom functions which are 'attached' to a particular button.  I've seen [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003025/javascript-how-do-i-call-functions-from-an-array-of-function-names), not exactly sure if that is applicable here.

Clearly `btn[i].function+"()";` isn't cutting it.

[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/x63nuo7a/1/)

How can I store a custom function within the button array, and successfully call it upon mouseclick?

Code follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {background-color: black; margin: 8px; }
        #canvas {border: 1px solid gray;}
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var $canvas = $("#canvas");
            var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
            var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
            var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
            var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
            var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();
            var cw = canvas.width;
            var ch = canvas.height;

            var btn = [{
                x: 50,
                y: 100,
                width: 80,
                height: 50,
                display: "Hello There",
                function: "functionA" // Is this right?
            }, {
                x: 150,
                y: 100,
                width: 80,
                height: 50,
                display: "Why Not?",
                function: "functionB" // Is this right?
            }, {
                x: 250,
                y: 100,
                width: 80,
                height: 50,
                display: "Let's Go!",
                function: "functionC" // Is this right?
            }];

            function drawAll() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
                for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
                    drawButton(ctx, btn[i].x, btn[i].y, btn[i].width, btn[i].height, btn[i].display);
                }
            }

            drawAll();

            // listen for mouse events
            $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
                handleMouseDown(e);
            });

            function handleMouseDown(e) {
                // tell the browser we'll handle this event
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                // save the mouse position
                lastX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
                lastY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

                // hit all existing buttons
                for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
                    if ((lastX < (btn[i].x + btn[i].width)) &&
                        (lastX > btn[i].x) &&
                        (lastY < (btn[i].y + btn[i].height)) &&
                        (lastY > btn[i].y)) {
                        // execute button function
                        btn[i].function+"()"; // obviously this is just wrong.
                        console.log("Button #" + (i + 1) + " has been clicked!!" );
                    }
                }
            }

            function drawButton(context, x, y, width, height, text) {
                var myGradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, y, 0, y + height);
                myGradient.addColorStop(0, '#999999');
                myGradient.addColorStop(1, '#222222');
                context.fillStyle = myGradient;
                context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                context.fillStyle = 'white';
                // textAlign aligns text horizontally relative to placement
                context.textAlign = 'center';
                // textBaseline aligns text vertically relative to font style
                context.textBaseline = 'middle';
                context.font = 'bold 15px sans-serif';
                context.fillText(text, x + width / 2, y + height / 2);
            }

            function functionA() {
                alert("Yipee Function A!");
            }

            function functionB() {
                alert("Yowza, it's Function B!");
            }

            function functionC() {
                alert("Now showing Function C!");
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: @Barmar, @sigmus, @doldt  you guys rock.  Now of course I can't remotely figure out who gets the win.  Sigmus for kicking me (deservedly so) for using the word `function` poorly.  Barmar for quick speed (correct answer first), doldt for awesome screen name.  My tendency is to go with Sigmus.  Unless... Tiebreaker = find a link of Mozilla Developer Network quality or better describing the correct procedure for this issue?   Anybody up for that?  I thought not... :^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your buttons to:

```
{
    display: "Hello There",
    action: functionA 
 }
```

And to invoke:

```
btn[i].action();
```

I changed the name `function` to `action` because `function` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an object property name.

Comment: It can be used as a property name, but you have to quote it. But I agree with your decision to rename it for ease of use. I showed the alternative in my answer.

Comment: Reserved words (such as `function`) are allowed as object property keys, see [MDN on Reserved Word Usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_word_usage) - no quotes needed either. Of course, it's probably still bad practice.

Comment: Follow-up to my comment above: using reserved words as property names [will not work on older browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/), even though it is allowed by the ES5 specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can store references to the functions in your array, just lose the `"` signs around their names *(which currently makes them strings instead of function references)*, creating the array like this:

```
var btn = [{
                x: 50,
                y: 100,
                width: 80,
                height: 50,
                display: "Hello There",
                function: functionA
            }, {
                x: 150,
                y: 100,
                width: 80,
                height: 50,
                display: "Why Not?",
                function: functionB
            }]
```

Then you can call either by writing `btn[i].function()`.

Comment: Do note that using reserved words as property names, such as `function`, is a bad practice, and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the name of the function in the array, put a reference to the function itself:

```
        var btn = [{
            x: 50,
            y: 100,
            width: 80,
            height: 50,
            display: "Hello There",
            'function': functionA
        }, {
            x: 150,
            y: 100,
            width: 80,
            height: 50,
            display: "Why Not?",
            'function': functionB
        }, {
            x: 250,
            y: 100,
            width: 80,
            height: 50,
            display: "Let's Go!",
            'function': functionC
        }];
```

To call the function, you do:

```
btn[i]['function']();
```

I've put `function` in quotes in the literal, and used array notation to access it, because it's a reserved keyword.