# Call dynamically methods in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, methods, dynamic

I'm trying to call a few methods dynamically in my React component.

so I have this code where I want to call a function `stepOne`, `stepTwo`, etc. whenever that step is achieved, but this needs to be dynamically called to add new steps in the future.

However I tried already a couple of methods (`hasOwnProperty`,`typeof this[methodName]`, `this.{methodName}()`) and can't get to call the right method.

Here is my code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props,State>{

    steps = [
        'stepOne',
        'stepTwo',
        'stepThree',
    ];

    state = {step:1};

    stepOne(){
        return 'This is Step One';
    }

    stepTwo(){
        return 'This is Step Two';
    }

    _getContent(){
        let content = 'Step not exists';

        const methodName = this.steps[this.state.step - 1];

        if (typeof this[methodName] === 'function') {
            content = this[methodName]();
        }
        return content;
    }

    render(){
        return '<div>' + this._getContent() + '</div>'
    }
}
```

In this example, I always get `undefined` in the `typeof this[methodName]` operation

Comment: does these steps have different behaviors ?

Comment: yes, they will have different behaviours and setting different variables in the state of the main component

Comment: this.[methodName] probably missing a 'dot'

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` when I add the dot :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript How do i call functions from an array of function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003025/javascript-how-do-i-call-functions-from-an-array-of-function-names)

Comment: did that help you?

Comment: I had already tried adding the parenthesis, but I get `TypeError: this[methodName] is not a function`. when I send to console `typeof this[methodName]` I get `undefined`

Comment: I was talking about link

Comment: No, I had already seen that link but that answer throwed the error mentioned before. The accepted answered is the one that worked for me. thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try creating the map of functions and bind this context to your created functions

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props,State>{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.stepOne = this.stepOne.bind(this);
        this.stepTwo = this.stepTwo.bind(this);
        this.funcMap = {
            '1': this.stepOne,
            '2': this.stepTwo
        };
        this.state = {step: '1'};
    }


    stepOne(){
        return 'This is Step One';
    }

    stepTwo(){
        return 'This is Step Two';
    }

    _getContent(){
        let content = 'Step not exists';

        const method = this.funcMap[this.state.step];

        if (typeof method === 'function') {
            content = method();
        }
        return content;
    }

    render(){
        return '<div>' + this._getContent() + '</div>'
    }
}
```

Comment: First adding 

this.stepOne = this.stepOne.bind(this);
        this.stepTwo = this.stepTwo.bind(this);

and then 

        this.funcMap = {
            '1': this.stepOne,
            '2': this.stepTwo
        };


resolved my issue

Comment: @Rajeshwar  
You can also avoid bind if you change your functions as arrow functions.